# Adding a new inherited "interface" and virtual methods require recompile

Tags: c++, dll, interface

There are existing answers that cover the general cases, but they are slightly vague and I need to be certain on this.

Consider:

- An existing defined class that derives from an abstract base class "interface".
- Class is a part of a library that is compiled into multiple dlls that talk to each other through the interface.

Then add:

- A second "interface" from which the defined class would now be derived (so now it has two interfaces).
- New virtual methods to the defined class that are accessed by the new interface.

Do I need to recompile every dll that links this library, or only the dlls that use the new methods?

**EDIT:**

My original interface exposes a dynamic method which is `Dynamic(int OP, void* args)` would it be possible to add an op that casts to the new interface?

How does COM manage to add new interfaces to objects without corrupting the existing interfaces? Does it stack interfaces, use multiple-inheritance, etc???

Let me lay out the way this works.

Statically Linked Library Interfaces

```
In statically linked library

class Interface1
{
    virtual Method1() = 0;
    virtual Method2() = 0;
}
class NotReallyInterface2 : Interface1
{
    virtual Method1() = 0;
    virtual Method2() { // does something }
}
```

In dlls

```
In A.dll

Load statically linked library
class A : NotReallyInterface2
{
    virtual Method1() { // does something }
}

In B.dll

Load statically linked library
class B: NotReallyInterface2
{
     virtual Method1() { // does something different }
}
```

I want to add

```
class Interface3
{
     virtual Method3() = 0;
}
```

I have some problem here because my inheritance structure looks like.

```
[a.dll [ library : Interface1 < NotReallyInterface2 ] < A ]
[b.dll [ library : Interface1 < NotReallyInterface2 ] < B ]
```

so I'm afraid

```
[ a.dll [ library : Interface1 < NotReallyInterface2 ] < Interface3 < A ]
```

won't work.

**Edit 2**

So I found my problem. Apparently, other dlls and executables are referencing my `NotReallyInterface2`. This means that multiple dlls and exes are building the same base class. So if those "copies" of the base class get out of sync, down goes the ship. Which means I can't change a single method signature in `NotReallyInterface2`.

This would have worked had no one referenced `NotReallyInterface2` and I now get that out of the answers and the whole thing makes sense.

Comment: This is why it is very important to get your interfaces right as early as possible.

Comment: @NeilKirk It's an issue with an established interface where I need to add new features to the class and be able to access them.

Comment: COM is a completely different issue.  Remember COM is cross language (VB and C++ and C# apps can all use COM objects.)   A complete answer to the "How does COM do it?" question would take more than a comment on StackOverflow.  Read about IUnknown and understand what it does and why they need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to recompile those DLLs that reference the derived class directly. Those that only reference it through the interface will continue to work.

COM relies on this very thing. The COM ABI specification effectively makes it a requirement for every compatible C++ compiler not to screw with vtables in a way that makes interfaces stop working. That's why one of the fundamental requirements of COM is that you never ever modify a published interface, by adding/removing/changing functions or giving it a new base interface.

Adding a new interface by having it derive the old one and make the implementing class derive from the new interface doesn't break that; neither does multiple inheritance from many interfaces in the implementing class.

The not-so-abstract class ought not to get in the way, but now you're outside the guarantees of COM. If that class has data members, it gets even worse. I *think* it would still be safe not to recompile the code, but I wouldn't want to rely on it anymore.

Comment: This conflicts with the other answers. Do you have an evidence to support your answer?

Comment: It's a simplification of Mats Petersson's answer - his gives you some guidelines about specific things you can do to avoid recompiling even more code. So my answer doesn't conflict with his, it's just more conservative.

Comment: As for Dale Wilson's radical viewpoint of "the compiler can screw up anything it wants", that's true from a C++ standard point of view, but you're using DLLs, which is incompatible with that view anyway. The guarantee that code only using the interface doesn't need to be recompiled when the implementing class changes comes directly from the way COM works, though. COM is designed so that components can be recompiled, and code that only uses the interfaces will keep working. It's an ABI guarantee that every compiler usable with COM has to give. That's almost every WIndows compiler, of course.

Comment: Then QueryInterface is used to safely cast to different interfaces?

Comment: What if I had some half-abstract class in the way?

Comment: QueryInterface is essentially a mechanism to put the cast, which is affected by implementing class, in the same DLL as the implementing class. The virtual dispatch insulates the code that uses it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid, the not-so-abstract class ruins it.

Comment: Let me point out one last time that the original question was NOT about COM but about C++. (COM showed up in a reply and a later edit) and I stand firmly behind my "radical" view that coding to the implementation details of a particular client is a very poor idea.  Yes, I have worked with compilers that had "Different" implementations of vtables, exceptions, template expansions, etc.  Even if you know it's a DLL meaning it probably runs only on Windows, MSVC is not the only compiler that runs on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Officially, any change to any class requires recompilation of everything that touches that class. The C++ standard, and most compiler manufactures documentation, does not make any guarantees with regards to "what happens if you change something in a class".

In practice, there are things you can do that will make this work. And there are things you can do that will definitely make everything break.

A second interface class will introduce a second vtable, which in turn means differences in the class that inherits both classes. This is almost certainly in the "break everything category", it will cause problems everywhere that uses that class in any what concerned about the "content" of the class.

Would it be possible to, instead add a new class that is derived from the original interface class?

So instead of:

```
 class Interface_A
 {
   public:
    virtual void func1();
    virtual int  func2();
    ...
 };

 class Interface_B
 {
   public:
    virtual int func6();
    ...
 };

 class myClass : public Interface_A, public Interface_B
 {
   ... 
 };
```

do this:

```
 class Interface_B : public Interface_A
 {
   public:
    virtual int func6();
    ...
 };


 class myClass : public Interface_B
 {
   ... 
 };
```

That would (in most instances) jut make the vtable a bit longer, which is much more acceptable to the rest of the code, and for any code that ONLY uses Interface_A's functionality, would not cause any problem at all. [Subject to compiler making a sensible job - the standard still allows the compiler to "mess everything up" if you do that. But I used to work for a company where we had A LOT of code that relied on other parts of the system "not changing", and we analysed and dealt with this sort of thing quite a bit].

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this, because there's an half-abstract base class in the way. I can see why COM needs a QueryInterface method.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new interface adds additional virtual methods which changes the layout of the vtable (internal compiler generated table to route virtual method calls.)  Thus you need to recompile every module that uses the class (or at least every one that creates/destroys or calls a virtual method on the class.)

Comment: qualifying my answer by "if you want to have any confidence in the application actually working"   As others have pointed out you can cheat and assume compiler implementation details.  You will usually get away with it, but not always.  (humor)Please don't do this on any software that effects me or any of my friends and relatives. (/humor)

Comment: You do realize that every program that uses COM on Windows (i.e. probably every single non-trivial one, somewhere under the hood) is doing this, right? Also, "affects" ;-p

Comment: COM does not use C++ virtual methods for its "inheritence"  (actually Aggregation"

Comment: Huh? The COM binary specification is modeled after the Microsoft C++ virtual dispatch mechanism, and that's the way you implement components in C++. What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: Read about IUnknown.   That's a concept that does not exist in C++.   This original question was about C++,  If it is a question about adding an interface in COM, then my answer is different. But just because they use the same name, don't be fooled into thinking that a COM interface is in any way the same as a C++ class containing only pure virtual methods (i.e. an interface).

Comment: To clarify further: COM uses c++ inheritance to create a much-more-robust way of extending classes (Aggregation).

Comment: He's on Windows (as evidenced by the existence of DLLs). He's using code that has exactly the same layout as the C++ mapping of COM (aside from the not-so-abstract class we learned about later). COM guarantees certain behavior. Thus I can derive that his code will exhibit the same behavior. (Unless you've got a weird compiler that special-cases hierarchies rooted in IUnknown.) Yes, it's a platform-specific answer, but so what? It's pretty much a platform-specific question.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Is this reliance on COM-guarantees a possibility because the compiler I'm using? And, are COM class interfaces pointing to separate members of the whole class (a composite class)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 2nd interface does not repeat any method full signature from 1st interface (in which case you should use virtual inheritance) AND in your implementation 2nd interface is actually 2nd:

```
ImplClass : public Interface1, Interface2
```

you don't need to recompile existing code that uses only Interface1. This is because ImplClass will now have two pointers to two vtables but 1st pointer will remain at the beginning of this class memory layout.

Also, if you used factory methods in your library, meaning that client code always got Interface* by calling something like Interface1* CreateInterface1 () method implemented in library (and never dealt with ImplClass* directly), and now this method got recompiled then you don't care even about interface order.

Comment: Will my not so abstract class get in the way?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand your last question. Could you please re-phrase it?